# Who are all the squad members in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

We have a list of [optional squad members](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53784/are-there-optional-squad-members-in-mass-effect-3) in Mass Effect 3 but I'm wondering what all possible squad mates are and what classes they are/what abilities they have. I'm curious about what my options are tactically.

What are all the squadmates in Mass Effect 3 (regardless of whether I can have them all at once)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your squad in ME3 consists of:

*The Virmire Survivor*, which means one of **Ashley** or **Kaidan**, as well as the return of **Garrus**, **Tali**, and **Liara**. In addition, two new members join the squad, **James**, and a newly corporeal **EDI**. If you own the *From Ashes* DLC, there is also **Javik**, the Prothean.

As for 'classes', the squad members don't have classes in the sense that Shepard does. Instead they each have their own unique set of 4 powers. Two are shared with one of the available Shepard classes, and two are unique to them, but can be unlocked as Bonus Powers through conversation.

Specifically, the lineup of powers for each looks something like this:

**Ashley Williams**

```
  Disruptor Ammo     Concussive Shot       Inferno Grenade   Marksman
```

**Kaidan Alenko**

```
  Reave              Barrier               Overload          Cryo Blast
```

**James Vega**

```
  Incendiary Ammo    Carnage               Fortification     Frag Grenade
```

**Garrus Vakarian**

```
 Concussive Shot     Armor-Piercing Ammo   Overload          Proximity Mine
```

**Liara T'Soni**

```
  Singularity        Warp                  Stasis            Warp Ammo
```

**Tali'Zorah vas Normandy**

```
 Defense Drone       Energy Drain          Combat Drone      Sabotage
```

**EDI**

```
 Incinerate          Overload              Defense Matrix    Decoy
```

**Javik**

```
 Dark Channel       Lift Grenade           Pull              Slam
```

Comment: Not played it in a while but I seem to remember that if you have the Citadel DLC then you can use any surviving squadmate from the previous games for the Citadel missions.

Answer (score 3):

Searching around on [**Mass Effect Wiki**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Characters) The constant squad members throughout the game are as follows:

- **Virmire Survivor**[Ash](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Ashley_Williams) or [Kaidan](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kaidan_Alenko)
- [**Liara T'Soni**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Liara_T%27Soni)
- [**Tali'Zorah vas Normandy**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tali%27Zorah_nar_Rayya)
- [**EDI**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/EDI)
- [**James Vega**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/James_Vega)
- [**Garrus Vakarian**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Garrus_Vakarian)
- [**Javik**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/The_Prothean) (DLC)

Answer (score 2):

Excluding future DLCs, here is your entire list of party members that are currently available:

- The Virmire survivor (Kaidan/Ashley)
- Tali'zorah vas Normandy
- Liara T'Soni
- Garrus Vakarian
- James Vega
- Javic The Prothean (DLC only)
- EDI

[Source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, you get Admiral Anderson for much of the first mission. There are also temporary squadmates in the DLCs.

**Omega**:

- Aria T'Loak
- A turian biotic called Nyreen Kandros

**Citadel**:

- Wrex shows up for the fight in the car lot
- Wrex and all ME2 squad members can participate in the Armax Arena simulated battles, except for Thane, Mordin, Morinth, and Legion.